# Ошибка после считывания с файла в цикле

Tags: циклы, c++-cli, foreach

После первого же прохода `for each` бросает ошибку:

> "Exception thrown: read access violation. **_Pnext** was 0x1929B2E7658. occurred".

```
void ABQuestion::readFromFile(std::ifstream * file) const
{
    Question::readFromFile(file);
    int answSize = answers.size();
    file->read((char*)&answSize, sizeof(int));
    for each(std::pair<char, std::string> answ in answers)
    {
        file->read((char*) &(answ.first),        sizeof(char));
        file->read((char*)&(answ.second), sizeof(std::string));
    }
}
```

Данные из файла считываются корректно. В конструкторе определена `'std::map <char, std::string> answers'`

```
ABQuestion::ABQuestion() : Question::Question()
{
    answers = { { 'a', "" },
                { 'b', "" },
                { 'c', "" },
                { 'd', "" } };
}
```

Если убрать строчки

```
file->read((char*) &(answ.first),        sizeof(char));
file->read((char*)&(answ.second), sizeof(std::string));
```

то эта ошибка не появляется(зато появляется другая).
Чем может быть вызвана и как исправить?

Comment: Чтение `std::string` заполняет объект невалидными данными.

Comment: "зато появляется другая" - интересно какая?
"как исправить" - удалите остальной код в методе readFromFile, сообщите результат:)

Comment: Удалил, запустил, та же ошибка в том же месте.

Comment: @VTT но данные же считаны корректно, считал то, что записал, ошибка возникает только после чтения.

Comment: Данные считаны корректно, но они не являются валидными. Чтение заполняет указатели внутри объекта `std::string` и делает их невалидными. Следует записать (а потом и считать) содержимое буфера, который хранится в `std::string`, а не сам объект `std::string`.

Comment: Чтение `(char*) &(answ.first)` тоже неверно,  `answ.first` не доступно для записи. Вообще не следует использовать c-style кастование.

Comment: @VTT Спасибо, заработало